# Unresolved external symbol "struct MonthlyBudget_cdecl actual(void)"

Tags: c++

I can't seem to find the problem in my code whether it be to me being sick or blind I'm unsure of. The error I get is:

```
unresolved external symbol"struct MonthlyBudget_cdecl actual(void)" (?actual@@YA?AUMonthlyBudget@@XZ) referenced in function_main.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <Windows.h>
    using namespace std;


    struct MonthlyBudget {
    double housing;
    double utilities;
    double householdExpenses;
    double transportation;
    double food;
    double medical;
    double insurance;
    double entertainment;
    double clothing;
    double misc;

        MonthlyBudget(double housingCost, double utilitiesCost, double householdExpensesCost, double transportationCost, double foodCost,
        double medicalCost, double insuranceCost, double entertainmentCost, double clothingCost, double miscCost) {
        housing = housingCost;
        utilities = utilitiesCost;
        householdExpenses = householdExpensesCost;
        transportation = transportationCost;
        food = foodCost;
        medical = medicalCost;
        insurance = insuranceCost;
        entertainment = entertainmentCost;
        clothing = clothingCost;
        misc = miscCost;
    }
    MonthlyBudget() {
        housing = 0;
        utilities = 0;
        householdExpenses = 0;
        transportation = 0;
        food = 0;
        medical = 0;
        insurance = 0;
        entertainment = 0;
        clothing = 0;
        misc = 0;
    }
    void setHousing(double housingCost) {
        housing = housingCost;
    }

    double getHousing() {
        return housing;
    }

    void setUtilities(double utilitiesCost) {
        utilities = utilitiesCost;
    }

    double getUtilities() {
        return utilities;
    }

    void setHouseholdExpenses(double householdEXCost) {
        householdExpenses = householdEXCost;
    }

    double getHouseholdExpenses() {
        return householdExpenses;
    }

    void setTransportation(double transportationCost) {
        transportation = transportationCost;
    }

    double getTransportation() {
        return transportation;
    }

    void setFood(double foodCost) {
        food = foodCost;
    }

    double getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    void setMedical(double medicalCost) {
        medical = medicalCost;
    }

    double getMedical() {
        return medical;
    }

    void setInsurance(double insuranceCost) {
        insurance = insuranceCost;
    }

    double getInsurance() {
        return insurance;
    }

    void setEntertainment(double entertainmentCost) {
        entertainment = entertainmentCost;
    }

    double getEntertainment() {
        return entertainment;
    }

    void setClothing(double clothingCost) {
        clothing = clothingCost;
    }

    double getClothing() {
        return clothing;
    }

    void setMisc(double miscCost) {
        misc = miscCost;
    }

    double getMisc() {
        return misc;
    }
};

     int main() {
    MonthlyBudget budget(500, 150, 65, 50, 250, 30, 100, 150, 75, 50);
    MonthlyBudget actual();
    double housing, utilities, householdExpenses, transportation, food, medical, insurance, entertainment, clothing, misc;
    cout << "How much did you spend on housing?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> housing;
        actual().setHousing(housing);
    } while (housing < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on utilities?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> utilities;
        actual().setUtilities(utilities);
    } while (utilities < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on household expenses?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> householdExpenses;
        actual().setHousing(householdExpenses);
    } while (householdExpenses < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on transportation?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> transportation;
        actual().setTransportation(transportation);
    } while (transportation < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on food?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> food;
        actual().setFood(food);
    } while (food < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on medical?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> medical;
        actual().setMedical(medical);
    } while (medical < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on insurance?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> insurance;
        actual().setInsurance(insurance);
    } while (insurance < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on entertainment?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> entertainment;
        actual().setEntertainment(entertainment);
    } while (entertainment < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on clothing?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> clothing;
        actual().setClothing(clothing);
    } while (clothing < 0);
    cout << "How much did you spend on misc?" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> misc;
        actual().setMisc(misc);
    } while (misc < 0);

    cout << "Showing projected budget compared to actual:" << endl;
    cout << "Housing: " << budget.housing - actual().housing << endl;
    cout << "Utilities: " << budget.utilities - actual().utilities << endl;
    cout << "Household Expenses: " << budget.householdExpenses - actual().householdExpenses << endl;
    cout << "Transportation: " << budget.transportation - actual().transportation << endl;
    cout << "Food: " << budget.food - actual().food << endl;
    cout << "Medical: " << budget.medical - actual().medical << endl;
    cout << "Insurance: " << budget.insurance - actual().insurance << endl;
    cout << "Entertainment: " << budget.entertainment - actual().entertainment << endl;
    cout << "Clothing: " << budget.clothing - actual().clothing << endl;
    cout << "Misc: " << budget.misc - actual().misc << endl;

    string input;
    cin >> input;
    return 0;
}//main()
```

Again thanks for any help! I know the code is pretty messy and there are better ways to do this, but for the life of me I can't think of anything with my flu right now.

Comment: `MonthlyBudget actual();` declares a function that accepts no parameters and returns a `MonthlyBudget`. You need to lose the `()` there, and everywhere else you use them with `actual`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks you so much! no idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed () from actual() and all mentions. Fixed the program.